# Why is my PageRank result in Mathematica converging this way?

Tags: equation-solving, graphs-and-networks

I am using this technique to find the PR of these 3 pages. It converges to something it shouldn't be. I tried the same iteration in Java and 2 pages come up with 1.333 and the other one as 0.666. Mathematica is calculating something differently. Here's my code:

```
g = {"Netscape" -> "Amazon", "Netscape" -> "Netscape", 
   "Amazon" -> "Netscape", "Amazon" -> "Microsoft", 
   "Microsoft" -> "Amazon"};
pr = PageRankVector[g]
GraphPlot[g, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Text[
     Framed[#2 <> "\n" <> 
       ToString[pr[[#3]]], {Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, 0.8], 
       FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0.94, 0.85, 0.36]}], #1] &), 
 DirectedEdges -> True]
```

Comment: You probably have a problem in your Java code or others settings for `TeleportProbability`. But 1.333 and 0.666 doesn't add up to one, which it should, so I am positive that you have an error in your Java code.

Comment: How do I set Teleport in Mathematica to 0? And in my Java, I am not using any damping at all, so it's the plain PR formula, as described here http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mining/websearch.pdf. I am getting the same results as Stanford, so probably because Mathematica is indeed using a teleportation probability.

Comment: You have to look in the documentation. ` PageRankVector[g,TeleportProbability->0]`

Answer (score 1):

In the case that this does not closed I'll answer this temporarily (so that there won't be so many unaswerd questions aound)

The problem is `TeleportProbability` as guessed by @Pickett. To set it to 0 you just have to look in the documentation.

`PageRankVector[g,TeleportProbability->0]`

Comment: Unfortunately setting the value to zero will cause `The value of option TeleportProbability -> 0 should be a positive machine real number less than 1.` and setting it to a small value did not produce the right result for me. I also tried some other things, but alas could not replicate the paper's result.

Comment: @Pickett Should I delete this A then?

Comment: Probably, the intention was right but in this case `TeleportProbability` seems to be only a part of the problem. The answer is probably `TeleportProbability`+normalization+some other difference.